# Populate listview multiple times using C# Class

Tags: c#, listview

I am trying to populate a `listview` each time a button is selected. At the moment I have the button populating the `listview` once each time. Each time a new value is entered it will overwrite the current `listview`.

I want to be able to add in a new item and continue till there is multiple rows.

```
protected void btnAddSkuBarcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var SKUS = new List<SkuBar>
    {
        new SkuBar {SkuBarcode = txtSkuBarcode.Text , Qty = txtQty.Text},
    };

    lvWebLabels.DataSource = SKUS;
    lvWebLabels.DataBind();
}

public class SkuBar
{
    public string SkuBarcode { get; set; }
    public string Qty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're creating a new variable (`SKUS`) every time the button is clicked.  When you bind to that new list, you lose anything previously bound to the control.

Since the list needs to persist in a greater scope than just the method, put it in something like class scope:

```
List<SkuBar> SKUS = new List<SkuBar>();
```

Then just add to the existing list:

```
protected void btnAddSkuBarcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SKUS.Add(new SkuBar {SkuBarcode = txtSkuBarcode.Text , Qty = txtQty.Text});

    lvWebLabels.DataSource = SKUS;
    lvWebLabels.DataBind();
}
```

Note that this will only work in a *stateful* system.  If by chance you're using WebForms then the object itself is also dropped from scope for each request, so you'd need to persist the data somewhere else.  Session state, database, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `List<T>` every time the button is clicked so you lose the previous one. Define the `List<T>` outside of the button press so it can be re-used:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class YourClass
    {
        List<SkuBar> SKUS;

        public YourClass() // Or form load or whatever
        {
            SKUS = new List<SkuBar>();
        }

        protected void btnAddSkuBarcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SKUS.Add(new SkuBar {SkuBarcode = txtSkuBarcode.Text , Qty = txtQty.Text});

            lvWebLabels.DataSource = SKUS;
            lvWebLabels.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```